# Finding Amount of Numbers in a certain range

Tags: python, numbers, range

I am working with a text file filled with strings of numbers that are seperated by white space. I am trying to find the amount of numbers in the file that have a value between 1 and 1,000,000. I currently have this which just prints the number. Any advice on how to find the amount of numbers?

```
for line in file: 
    for number in line:
        if "0" < number < "1000000":
            print(number)
```

Comment: A hint: Initialize a count variable before the loops, and then keep adding one to that variable whenever you find a number meeting the criteria.

Comment: Have a variable that you increment each time you get a match

Comment: This is *not* the correct way.

Comment: do you have multiple numbers in each line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
file_object = open("numbers", "r")
count = 0
for line in file_object:    
    for number in line.split():
        if int(number) > 10 and int(number) < 100:
            count = count + 1
print(count)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: I hate to bug you again, but do you know if there is a way to  loop through multiple ranges without reentering. i.e. 0-100, 101-200, etc.

Comment: sure, just duplicate the if block, change "if" to "elif" (means: else if) and change the range. (see: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_if_else.htm)

Answer (score 4):

Your approach is **incorrect** since:

- `number` is every *character* of a line. So these can only be digits, letters, etc. Not multi-digit numbers; and
- comparison with strings is *lexicographically*.

You can however easily calculate this like:

```
sum(0 < int(n) < 1000000 for line in file for n in line.split() if n.strip())
```

The `int(..)` casts a string to its equivalent (integral) number. So `'100'` is converted to `100`. This is necessary if we want to perform *numerical comparisons*.

The `split()` is used to obtain the numbers in the file. It will look for whitespace, etc. and split on these parts.

The `if n.strip()` can be optional if the number is well formatted. But this can be problematic: for instance if you have tailing new lines, etc.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

If they file has only numbers, you can use something like:

```
with open(path, 'r') as f:
    print sum(1 for x in f.read().split() if 10000 > int(x) > 0 )
```

This will count the numbers in the whole file without counting each line separately.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

First, cast your `number` variable to an int like this: `int(number)` and use ints instead of strings to compare. Like this: `if 0 < int(number) < 10000`.

Also, add a counter like some comments suggested. Here is the completed code:

```
counter = 0
for line in file: 
    for number in line:
        if 0 < number < 1000000:
            counter += 1
```